# Column Constraint Sql 2008

Tags: sql, constraints

I have been trying to find out if I can make a column Open on Insert, and closed on Update.
What I mean by that, is I need a column that I can give it a value only on Insert, but if I try to give it a value with Update, the statement would fail.

I am working with SQL 2008...

Comment: Connect item [Add DRI to enforce immutable column values](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/346200/add-dri-to-enforce-immutable-column-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with constraints - you need to use [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) for this.

> A trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically executes when an event occurs in the database server. DML triggers execute when a user tries to modify data through a data manipulation language (DML) event. DML events are INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements on a table or view.